# Using Kafka instead of spring cloud bus

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud

Let me explain my problem using an example,

- There is a micro service called "notification-service"
- It has 2 instances running in port 8080 and 8081
- We have our **Spring cloud config server** also running and contain all
  property files of "notification-service"

When property file get changed, to make it immediately effect to the all running instances, we can use spring-cloud-bus,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and use postman tool to refresh all instances of "notification-service" at once.

- e.g., localhost:8080/bus/refresh

The thing i want to know is are there any way to do this using kafka instead of spring cloud bus?

Comment: spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for this?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And it's called [Spring Cloud Stream](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/)